# How to fix remote desktop connection which works on one computer but not another with same setup and connection?

Tags: windows-7, windows, networking, remote-desktop

I'm able to get remote desktop access to my office's computer on my home laptop but can't do so on the home desktop. Here may be relevant information:

Office computer: Windows 7 64-bit.
Laptop: Windows 7 32-bit, Avira antivirus.
Home desktop: Windows 64-bit, Avira antivirus. Same wifi network with the laptop

Avira may not do anything with this, as I disable it on home desktop but still can't get the connection. Also, I can get connection on the laptop with Avira on. So where should I look at to identify and fix this problem?

Comment: Are both the laptop and the home desktop domain-joined? The admin might have decided to enforce NLA-only logins (i.e.: only from domain-joined machines).

Comment: @cdavid Both of them were joined to WORKGROUP instead of domain. I think the problem isn't from the admin side, e.g., the remote connection doesn't require any permission from admin.